# Checkbox's IsChecked property never changes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, imultivalueconverter

I have a `TreeView` setup with a `HierarchialDataTemplate`. It's `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of `Overlay` objects in my viewmodel, where each `Overlay` has a collection of `Layer` objects (thus the `HierarchialDataTemplate`). For each `Overlay`, I'm displaying a `CheckBox` and a `Label` which is simply bound to the `Overlay`'s `Name` property.

Each time one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked, the current `Overlay` and the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` will be sent as command parameters to my viewmodel. I'm using a `MultiValueConverter` to send these.

My issue is that the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` never changes. I've tried using both `DataTriggers` and setting the `Command` property directly, but I get the same result.

Below is the related .xaml for the `TreeView`. This is using the `Command` property.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding OverlaysViewSource}" Name="LayersTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" >
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetLayersCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                </CheckBox>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Here's the version using `DataTriggers`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding OverlaysViewSource}" Name="LayersTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" >
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetLayersCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" >
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}" />
                                        <Binding/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SetLayersCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" >
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}"/>
                                        <Binding />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Here's my `MultiValueConverter`:

```
public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)values[0];
        Overlay overlay = (Overlay)values[1];
        return new object[] { cb.IsChecked, overlay };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm checking the `IsChecked` value in both the converter and the command in my view model. It never changes. The GUI never reflects a change in the `CheckBox` either.

Comment: What if you put a boolean property in the Layers object and bind IsChecked to that? Then you can simple pass the layer in the command and not worry about the multibinding. (Don't worry about the vote to close, there is some serial vote-to-close person patrolling the wpf tag.)

Comment: So the `Overlay` and `Layer` objects are third party objects that are used extensively in the app. I'd rather not create a new class for this but looks like I might have to go that route. I just don't understand why the checkbox wouldn't change.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the first binding should be to the IsChecked property rather than the control itself.